# Visual Studio Community 2015 debugger ends at conditional breakpoint with "Evaluation of native methods is not supported" - how do I fix?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2015, breakpoints

I have a conditional breakpoint and the condition checks the value of a string and stops if it's true. It stops but then a window opens saying:

`The condition for a breakpoint failed to execute ... The error returned was 'Evaluation of method System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection.get_Item() calls into native method 'System.Globalization.TextInfo.Internal.GetCaseInsHash(). Evaluation of native methods in this context is not supported.'. Click OK to stop at this breakpoint.`

I searched for answers but they said enable Managed Compatibility Mode, which didn't work.

Comment: Do you have other VS Environment to test it? The similar issue has been reported before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169728/system-math-abs-calls-into-native-method-system-appdomain-getid, if possible, you could share a simple sample using one drive, I will help you debug it using different VS versions, at least, we could know that whether it is related to the VS versions or it really has a limitation for it. If you could share it, please also tell me where and how you set the condition breakpoint.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Yes, I just tried it in Visual Studio Community 2017. Exact same result. The answer you linked was no help.

Comment: Project > Properties > Debug > uncheck option Enable Native code debugging, how about the result? In addition, do you restart your app after you enable Managed Compatibility Mode? No sample is hard for us to troubleshoot this issue, if possible, share a simple sample using one drive would be better.

Comment: Didn't work and I ended up giving up and re-publishing and using a new condition that didn't call any methods the debugger didn't like.

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276732/error-when-using-a-conditional-breakpoint-on-system-type

Comment: i was getting this error when i had added some linq expressions in my Watch window. When I used the watched expression directly in code. i did not receive any error.

Answer (score 6):

Checking "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" under project debug settings solved this problem for me.

Comment: @timelmer is it really named like this? I cannot find this option anywhere (VS 15.7.5)

Comment: Not sure. I'm not seeing it anymore, but I may be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Make sure you are looking in project properties Debug tab, not Visual Studio debug options.

Comment: @timelmer Right click on the project name. Select Properties. Select Debug. At the bottom of the script you will find the Enable native code debugging.

Answer (score 5):

You could perhaps also manually add the breakpoint to your code, like so...

```
if (conditionThatMeansStop) 
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
}
```

That's how I got around...

```
Evaluation of method System.String.op_Equality calls into the native method System.Environment.FailFast()
```

... in a similar situation where I was trying to set a conditional endpoint that checked a string's value.